# Underwater Housing for Sony A7s for surfing photography?

Tags: sony, sony-alpha, underwater

I have a Sony a7s and I would like to start to shoot surfing photography.

I never had an underwater housing before, so I feel a little bit lost. Besides, it's difficult to understand if all buttons/features of my a7s will be available once inside the housing. For example, [this Meikon housing](https://meikon.com.hk/collections/underwater-waterproof-camera-housing-case-for-sony-camera/products/sony-a7-ng-series-40m-130ft-uw-housing-with-6-dome-port-pistol-grip-standard-port-white), looks great, but I am not sure if it is fully compatible with my camera.

Is a7s camera compatible with a7 housings spending <1000$?? Or are major differences that should I be concerned about?

What are good alternatives for my camera? Notice that I would like a pistol grip, which is crucial for one handed shootings.

Answer (score 2):

You should check with surf photographers and companies for this. Waves are different than underwater and the housings are too. I think surf photographers use housings custom-built for surf.

Here's an article on Clarke Little. He shoots giant shore pound in Hawaii which is the roughest on cameras:

[image]

https://petapixel.com/2013/04/05/interview-with-shorebreak-photographer-clark-little/